# Why is the second while loop in KMP not a conditional statement?

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings, exact-string-matching

When building the partial match table for KMP:

```
void buildBackTable() { 
    int i = 0, j = -1; b[0] = -1; 
    while (i < m) { 
        while (j >= 0 && P[i] != P[j]) j = b[j]; //Why is this a while loop!?
        i++; j++;
        b[i] = j;
    }
}
```

How come that second while loop is not a conditional instead? Such as:

```
void buildBackTable() { 
    int i = 0, j = -1; b[0] = -1; 
    while (i < m) { 
        if (j >= 0 && P[i] != P[j]) j = b[j]; //Why not?
        i++; j++;
        b[i] = j;
    }
}
```

In most of the examples I've tried, this statement is used to reset j to -1 when there is no match, so when the next iteration comes, we compare the first character of the string (P[j]) with the character at position i (P[i]). Is there an example where the while loop would be needed? I would love to see one. I've tried several samples of my own and changing the statement to a conditional would not make a difference (hence my question).

Comment: Have you tried random testing to search for an example where it makes a difference?  e.g., instrument your code to see if the while loop ever executes more than one iteration; generate one million random test cases on short strings; and run your code on all of those test cases to see if it ever trips the instrumentation.  That might help you form a conjecture.  (If you want to get sophisticated, if none of the test cases finds an example where it makes a difference, you could even try using Klee to search more systematically for examples.)